# python regular expression, cut multiple line

Tags: python, regex

Have read `re.M` but still no idea how to achieve this (in reasonable approach)

Source string is:

```
'ClassId=A1\n    classname=A1\n   \nClassId=B1\n    classname=B1\n '
```

Question is how to split it to two elements list below:

```
targe[0]='ClassId=A1\n    classname=A1'
targe[1]='ClassId=B1\n    classname=B1'
```

Answer (score 1):

`re.M` probably doesn't do what you think it does. See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.M). You might be looking for [`re.S` (`re.DOTALL`)](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.S) instead, but you don't need either in this case:

```
import re

string = 'ClassId=A1\n    classname=A1\n   \nClassId=B1\n    classname=B1\n '

regex = re.compile('ClassId=\w+\n    classname=\w+')

matches = regex.findall(string)
```

Comment: The content of source string is dynamic, like this, what I want is split ClassId object. So only 'ClassId=' is the pattern can be use.

ClassId=123
    classname=1
    superclass=3    
    InstanceId=4
      classname=5
      Caption=6     
   
ClassId=A123
    classname=A1
    superclass=A3    
    InstanceId=A4
      classname=A5
      Caption=A6

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'ClassId=A1\n    classname=A1\n   \nClassId=B1\n    classname=B1\n '
>>> re.findall('ClassId=(.*)\n    classname=(.*)', s)         
[('A1', 'A1'), ('B1', 'B1')]
```

This find the two fields that I assume can change. Simply putting the newline into the regexp works just fine.

You mention `re.M` — that flag is used when you want `^` and `$` to match on each line in the string, not just at the beginning and end of the string. That's not needed here since you can just put the newlines into your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Split on two newlines separated by one or more spaces,
then strip trailing whitespace.

```
>>> import re
>>> target=[p.rstrip() for p in re.split('\n +\n', 'ClassId=A1\n    classname=A1\n   \nClassId=B1\n    classname=B1\n ')]
>>> target[0]
'ClassId=A1\n    classname=A1'
>>> target[1]
'ClassId=B1\n    classname=B1'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with [`re.M`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE), as it would allow you to make good use of `^` and `$`.

Here's one possible way to achieve what you want:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s = 'ClassId=A1\n    classname=A1\n   \nClassId=B1\n    classname=B1\n '
>>> r = re.compile(r'^ClassId=.*$\s*classname=.*$', re.M)
>>> r.findall(s)
['ClassId=A1\n    classname=A1', 'ClassId=B1\n    classname=B1']
```

**UPDATE**

Below is a more general solution that splits the text into blocks of lines that start with a `ClassId` line.

```
import re, pprint

s = """\
ClassId=123
    classname=1
    superclass=3
    InstanceId=4
    classname=5
    Caption=6
ClassId=A123
    classname=A1
    superclass=A3
InstanceId=A4
    classname=A5
    Caption=A6
ClassId=B999
ClassId=
ClassId=A123 classname=A1
superclass=A3
"""

r = re.compile(r'^ClassId=.*?(?:(?=^ClassId=)|\Z)', re.M | re.S)

pprint.pprint(r.findall(s))
```

Output:

```
['ClassId=123\n    classname=1\n    superclass=3\n    InstanceId=4\n    classname=5\n    Caption=6\n',
 'ClassId=A123\n    classname=A1\n    superclass=A3\nInstanceId=A4\n    classname=A5\n    Caption=A6\n',
 'ClassId=B999\n',
 'ClassId=\n',
 'ClassId=A123 classname=A1\nsuperclass=A3\n']
```

Comment: @brike. I have updated my answer with a more general solution.

Comment: thank you, I have worked out the solution.  re.S is working for me, actually my question is how to include '\n' in regex match result.